# STM32H745XI graphical display

Tags: display, resolution, ide

I am planning to interface an [STM32H745XI](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h745xi.pdf) to a 1400x480 display. The maximum resolution given for the STM is 480×480. I understand that this is the maximum frequency the device can actually output.

Even I want to interface up to 480×480, is it possible? How to find out what will be the maximum resolution a particular display can support?

I am using Embedded Wizard for graphical libraries and Keil IDE for code editing.

Comment: The datasheet says the STM32 you have supports up to 1024x768 resolution. The display supports whatever it supports. It is unclear if you are connecting to a TFT panel directly or to a monitor, so better mention that.

Comment: Yeah you are right,STM32 support up to 1024x768 resolution. Is it possible to interface more than that resolution.